# Nosetests-script.py error - running tests from Needle

Tags: python, css, selenium, nosetests, needle-python

I am facing problems after trying to run the default test from Needle. Neddle is a tool for testing CSS using Selenium, here is their site : http://needle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

I already installed selenium, pip and needle, but, I am still facing problems after running the following command:

nosetests test_bbc.py --with-save-baseline:

Here is the response I got:

[image: no such option --with-save-baseline]

I have the file nosetests-script.py on my /Scripts folder, but It is very simple, here is the screenshoot:

[image: nosetests code]

I believe I am missing something very simple, but I could not find neither the cause or a solution here at stackoverflow.

### -

**Edit:**
Thank you for your suggestion [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe), After configuring carefully my Python 3.3, It worked! I am not sure if this was the cause because I believe that I did not installed nose on the Python 3.4, but thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, first look shows that `needle` [doesn't claim](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/needle) support for Python3.4, 3.3 is the latest. Can you try the same on 3.3?

Comment: Hi Alecxe, thank you for your fast reponse and for adding the needle tag, I tried and got the same message on python 3.3 as well. :/ I will edit my post

Comment: Actually I was using some libraries from Python 3.4. After installing pip, nose and needle on Python 3.3, It worked! Although, I am not sure if I installed nose on Python 3.4. Thank you for your help

Comment: Good! I would also try clean Python 3.4 virtual environment too. May be it is not the version problem really. Just in case.

Comment: I installed nose on Python 3.4 and It did not work, It is a compatibility Issue. Could you add an answer so I can mark as the accepted one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`needle`'s PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/needle) and it's [travis configuration](https://github.com/bfirsh/needle/blob/master/.travis.yml), Python 3.4 is not supported.

The latest supported version is 3.3.